# Syntax error when creating database SQLite python

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax-error

This is my code:

```
conn.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Blockchain_transactions(
        hash_of_previous_block CHAR PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NULL,
        id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
        transaction CHAR DEFAULT NULL
    );""")
```

It generates a syntax error

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "transaction": syntax error
```

REMARK: This comes earlier in my code and does not generate the same error

```
conn.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Blockchain_blocks (
        hash_of_previous_block CHAR PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NULL,
        proof_of_work INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
        difficulty INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
    );""")
```

Answer (score 4):

`transaction` is a [sqlite keyword](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Change the column name to something different and it will work.

Avoid reserved keywords for column names, or escape them like this:

```
conn.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Blockchain_transactions(
    hash_of_previous_block CHAR PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NULL,
    id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `transaction` CHAR DEFAULT NULL
);""")
```

Other possibilities to escape / quote keywords can be found in the linked keywords page.